# How do I get ID of the current logged-in user in the Sandbox environment from Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform-of-trust

Every user getting registered to the Sandbox gets added to the Platform as an Identity.
How can I get the Identity ID of my user when I log in to the [Sandbox environment](https://world-sandbox.oftrust.net/)?
I need this user ID for creating links between identities as is exemplified [in this guide](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/integrate-data-source-60-minutes/#step-3-create-a-group) after creating group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to check request from browser's network after you log in:
https://world-sandbox.oftrust.net/api/me

See the id in response
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `/me` endpoint of `Login API` in Platform of Trust, you can retrieve the identity ID of the user currently logged in to Sandbox.

Sample request in cURL is:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ...qW1QhdEsJLNGV2YA" \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/me"
```

On success, you should get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200

{
    "@context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/LegalParty/Person/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "33237067-14c3-4801-9e50-bf08406406e2",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "role": "developer",
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Bar"
}
```

You can [get your Bearer token](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/get-bearer-token/#how-to-get-bearer-token) (valid for 24 hours) from the Sandbox environment.

You may need to obtain the identity ID for your user when you are [building apps](https://developer.oftrust.net/guides/building-apps-platform/) in the Platform and creating authorization flow for the intended users.

You can access the API documentation for Platform of Trust Login API [here](https://docs.oftrust.net/#Login).